# Aggregate nested lists without nested loops in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm about to work my way into python's 3.5 lambda notation and I'm wondering wether nested loops can simply be replaced with a lambda one-liner. 
e.g.:
I have this simple dummy class hierarchy:

```
class Resource:
    def __init__(self, name="foo"):
        self.name = name

class Course:
    def __init__(self):
        self.resources = list()

class College:
    def __init__(self):
        self.courses = list()
```

I have an instance of `College`with multiple `Courses` and `Resources` as my starting point.

```
college = College()
```

Now if I want a `list`of all the `Resources` in my `College` I could easily do this with 2 `for-loops`:

```
all_resources = list()
for course in  college.courses:
    for resource in course.resources:
        all_resources.append(resource)
```

This is indeed very simple but I wondered whether I could also achieve this by doing something like this:

```
all_resources = list(map(lambda r: r, [c.resources for c in college.courses]))
```

But unfortunately this gives me a `list`of `lists` and not a `list`of `Resources`, what I wanted to achieve. Is lambda suitable for something like that?
What would be the most pythonic way for a operation like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, please stop creating empty lists by calling `list()` — it's both simpler and quicker to use a literal empty list `[]` (cheeck this with `timeit` if you don't believe me).

Secondly, there is absolutely no need to use `lambda` to create the list you want. A simple list comprehension will do the job:

```
all_resources = [r for r in course.resources for course in college.courses]
```

Don't overthink it. Keep it as simple as you can.

Comment: I think these loops are the wrong way round? 
It should be:



```all_resources = [r for course in college.courses for r in course.resources]```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using lambdas for this. You should be list comprehensions.

```
all_resources = [resource for resource for course in college.courses in course.resources]
```

Lambdas would be completely unnecessary here. If you absolutely wanted to, you could do something like:

```
all_resources = []
[(lambda c: [all_resources.append(r) for r in c])(x) for x in college.courses)]
```

But I'd recommend the first one. An alternative giving a different order would be

```
all_resources = [resource for resource in course.resources for course in college.courses]
```